# Not receiving archivelogs from production to remote side

Tags: oracle, rman, disaster-recovery

I have a scenario in which we have Designed data guard. Where we have 2 standby sides. One standby is located locally and 2nd standby is located on remote side. The distance between local and remote sides is about 268 KM. we were using 6MB of internet.
We have tested both local and remote standby database before moving the remote standby to remote location, both worked fine. 
Now after moving the remote standby to remote side it is not receiving the archive-logs. 
What should i do.?
Is there any problem with the distance?

---

In the alertlog the following  block of error messages appears rather frequently every 5 to 10 minues.

```
Thu Jan 15 10:35:15 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
Thu Jan 15 10:35:15 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc3_19506.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
PING[ARC3]: Heartbeat failed to connect to standby 'remotedr'. Error is 12170.
```

To shorten the logfile n succesive appearences of this block is abbreviated by `[n times the block ]`

> alertlogs

```
Thu Jan 15 10:24:28 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2794 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 2794 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo01.log
Thu Jan 15 10:24:50 2015
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 2795
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 2794 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo01.log
Thu Jan 15 10:24:50 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2795 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 2795 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo02.log
Thu Jan 15 10:26:28 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_lns2_27620.trc:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Thu Jan 15 10:26:28 2015
LGWR: I/O error 3113 archiving log 2 to 'remotedr'
Thu Jan 15 10:27:06 2015
ARC3: Attempting destination LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_3 network reconnect (3113)
ARC3: Destination LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_3 network reconnect abandoned
PING[ARC3]: Error 3113 when pinging standby remotedr.
Thu Jan 15 10:30:13 2015
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 2796
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 2 seq# 2795 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo02.log
Thu Jan 15 10:30:20 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2796 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 2796 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo03.log
Thu Jan 15 10:30:20 2015
LNS: Failed to archive log 2 thread 1 sequence 2795 (3113)
[8 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 11:36:20 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2797 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 2797 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo01.log
[9 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 12:48:23 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2798 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 2798 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo02.log
[2 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 13:03:09 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_j000_2208.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 273631
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ORA-00001: unique constraint (MACCOUNT.BO_TRANSNO_MCODE_PK) violated
ORA-06512: at "MACCOUNT.BO_LOAD_DATA", line 948
.) violated
[7 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 14:00:52 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2799 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 2799 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo03.log
[10 times the block ]  
Thu Jan 15 15:21:26 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2800 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 2800 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo01.log
[3 times the block ]
LNS2 started with pid=86, OS id=29188
Thu Jan 15 15:51:22 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2801 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 2801 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo02.log
[1 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 15:54:31 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
LGWR: Error 12170 creating archivelog file 'remotedr'
Thu Jan 15 15:54:31 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_lns2_29188.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
LNS: Failed to archive log 2 thread 1 sequence 2801 (12170)
Thu Jan 15 15:54:34 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
Thu Jan 15 15:54:34 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc1_19502.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
FAL[server, ARC1]: Error 12170 creating remote archivelog file 'remotedr'
FAL[server, ARC1]: FAL archive failed, see trace file.
Thu Jan 15 15:54:34 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc1_19502.trc:
ORA-16055: FAL request rejected
ARCH: FAL archive failed. Archiver continuing
Thu Jan 15 15:54:34 2015
ORACLE Instance orant - Archival Error. Archiver continuing.
[1 times the block ]
LNS2 started with pid=153, OS id=5535
Thu Jan 15 16:15:31 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2802 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 2802 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo03.log
[1 times the block ]  
Thu Jan 15 16:18:40 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
LGWR: Error 12170 creating archivelog file 'remotedr'
Thu Jan 15 16:18:40 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_lns2_5535.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
LNS: Failed to archive log 3 thread 1 sequence 2802 (12170)
Thu Jan 15 16:18:52 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
Thu Jan 15 16:18:52 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc0_19500.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
FAL[server, ARC0]: Error 12170 creating remote archivelog file 'remotedr'
FAL[server, ARC0]: FAL archive failed, see trace file.
Thu Jan 15 16:18:52 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc0_19500.trc:
ORA-16055: FAL request rejected
ARCH: FAL archive failed. Archiver continuing
Thu Jan 15 16:18:52 2015
ORACLE Instance orant - Archival Error. Archiver continuing.
[3 times the block ]
LNS2 started with pid=116, OS id=17902
Thu Jan 15 16:49:00 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 2803 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 2803 mem# 0: /oracle/oradata/orant/redo01.log
[1 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 16:52:09 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
LGWR: Error 12170 creating archivelog file 'remotedr'
Thu Jan 15 16:52:09 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_lns2_17902.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
LNS: Failed to archive log 1 thread 1 sequence 2803 (12170)
Thu Jan 15 16:52:15 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
Thu Jan 15 16:52:15 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc1_19502.trc:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
FAL[server, ARC1]: Error 12170 creating remote archivelog file 'remotedr'
FAL[server, ARC1]: FAL archive failed, see trace file.
Thu Jan 15 16:52:15 2015
Errors in file /oracle/admin/orant/bdump/orant_arc1_19502.trc:
ORA-16055: FAL request rejected
ARCH: FAL archive failed. Archiver continuing
Thu Jan 15 16:52:15 2015
ORACLE Instance orant - Archival Error. Archiver continuing.
[1 times the block ]
Thu Jan 15 17:06:49 2015
Error 12170 received logging on to the standby
Thu Jan 15 17:06:50 2015
```

> any suggestion how to solve this problem.
>   i think the network link is weak. because when i try to check the archive log list

`SQL> archive log list
Database log mode              Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Enabled
Archive destination            /ora/archives
Oldest online log sequence     2825
Next log sequence to archive   2827
Current log sequence           2827`

But when i check the sequence#

```
SQL> select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log;

 MAX(SEQUENCE#)
 --------------
        2816
```

i have set the

`fal_client=remotedr (standby database)
fal_server=orant (primary database)`

Comment: What is written in the primary alertlog for the remote archive destinations? How do you ship (logwriter or arch) sync/async, what configuration (max performance/ max protection)? async with arch, 1500KM is no problem with even worse connections.

Comment: using logwriter and configuration is max performance (async). Sorry but i dont have alertlogs right now.
`alter system set log_archive_dest_2 = 'SERVICE=drorant LGWR ASYNC VALID_FOR=(ONLINE_LOGFILES,ALL_ROLES) DB_UNIQUE_NAME=drorant';

alter system set log_archive_dest_3 = 'SERVICE=remotedr LGWR ASYNC VALID_FOR=(ONLINE_LOGFILES,ALL_ROLES) DB_UNIQUE_NAME=remotedr';
`

Comment: Well, without alertlog errors I need a magic bowl. Get the alertlog, read and weap. Verly likely it has a pointer to the problem.

Comment: can you telnet from the primary site to the remote listener port? I don't think so:ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred PING[ARC3]: Heartbeat failed to connect to standby 'remotedr'. Error is 12170. My guess: a firewall is blocking you.

Comment: yes i can telnet from primary to remote

Comment: I have checked firewall was disabled

Comment: ok, but can you also reach the remote listener port? 'telnet remotehost listenerport' Is the remote listener running? How is the alias remotedr defined?

Comment: tnsnames.ora entry was "remotedr". listener.ora entry was "remotedr.lse.com"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is related to network config, e.g. DNS / IP address / firewall, etc.

Can you sqlplus to the tns "remotedr" from primary?

You should get something along "sqlplus failed because instance not opened", if the config ia correct.

If not, you may try step by step turning off firewall, convert DNS to IP in tnsnames.ora.

**

> update:

**

i suspect the init parameters fal_server, fal_client are incorrect, it should be like this:

primary site: 
fal_server = standby
fal_client = primary

standby site: 
fal_server = primary 
fal_client = standby

the role of fal server is to receive update from primary and update the standy, therefore, under normal times when the primary is active, it would connect to fal server on standby, and push change vectors to standby.

however, in DR times the primary roles would be switched over to standby, the previous primary now assumes the role of fal server, the new primary would now connect the new standby and push change vectors to it, hence the config for standby site.

Comment: yes i can sqlplus using connection string of "remotedr" from primary. Please check my question i have updated some information.